# How to detect any mouse click on PySide Gui?

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt, pyside

I am trying implement a feature such that when a mouse is clicked on the gui, a function is triggered

Below is my mouse click detection, it doesn't work when I click on any part of the gui

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

import sys


class Main(QWidget):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        layout  = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("this is the main frame"))
        layout.gui_clicked.connect(self.anotherSlot)

    def anotherSlot(self, passed):
        print passed
        print "now I'm in Main.anotherSlot"


class MyLayout(QHBoxLayout):
    gui_clicked = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyLayout, self).__init__(parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print "Mouse Clicked"
        self.gui_clicked.emit("emit the signal")



a = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

This is my goal

```
Mouseclick.gui_clicked.connect(do_something)
```

Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can do a few things to help getting answers go smoothly.  Try to include as much _relevant_ information as possible.  Simply saying "it doesn't work" will not get you very far.  Include any error messages, or debugging output you've gotten (the latter is something you definitely want here).  Be sure also to  only include _bare minimum_ amount of code, which it looks like you've done well here, so well done! Do some debugging and post the output here and you'll be on the right track

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, so I havn't experience any error so far, the gui window did pop up with labels that I input, the main issue is that the mouse clicks are not register when I click the gui, I am not exactly sure how to debug this besides reading the documentation on the Qt Event, which I have being doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `mousePressEvent` inside `Main`:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *

import sys


class Main(QWidget):


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main, self).__init__(parent)

        layout  = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("this is the main frame"))

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        #print mouse position
        print QMouseEvent.pos()


a = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
sys.exit(a.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but I don't really see what's the difference, can I not pass in QMouseEvent into another class that I extend?

Comment: @Kevin Accordind the http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QMouseEvent.html docs: `The PySide.QtGui.QMouseEvent class contains parameters that describe a mouse event.

Mouse events occur when a mouse button is pressed or released inside a widget, or when the mouse cursor is moved`. So, you can use QMouseEvent in any class that inherited from `QWidget`. QHBoxLayout http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QHBoxLayout.html#qhboxlayout hasn't `mousePressEvent` function.

Comment: @NorthCat, this answer is not entirely true. If there is any widget inside `Main` that handles `mousePressEvent` (say a `QPushButton`) then `Main` won't receive that event.

Answer (score 2):

This can get complicated depending on your needs. In short, the solution is an [`eventFilter`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters) installed on the application. This will listen the whole application for an event. The problem is "event propagation". If a widget doesn't handle an event, it'll be passed to the parent (and so on). You'll see those events multiple times. In your case, for example `QLabel` doesn't do anything with a mouse press event, therefore the parent (your main window) gets it.

If you actually filter the event (i.e. you don't want the original widget to respond to the event), you won't get that problem. But, I doubt that this is your intent.

A simple example for just monitoring:

```
import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MouseDetector(QtCore.QObject):
    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print 'mouse pressed', obj
        return super(MouseDetector, self).eventFilter(obj, event)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QLabel('this is a label'))
        layout.addWidget(QtGui.QPushButton('Button'))

        self.setLayout(layout)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mouseFilter = MouseDetector()
    app.installEventFilter(mouseFilter)

    main = MainWindow()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

You can see that, clicking on the `QLabel` will give you something like:

```
mouse pressed <PySide.QtGui.QLabel object at 0x02B92490>
mouse pressed <__main__.MainWindow object at 0x02B92440>
```

Because, `QLabel` receives the event and since it doesn't do anything with it, it's ignored and passed to the parent (`MainWindow`). And it's caught by the filter/monitor again.

Clicking on the `QPushButton` doesn't have any problem because it uses that event and does not pass to the parent.

***PS:*** *Also note that this can cause performance problems since you are inspecting every single event in the application.*